# Code Has Suddenly Failed to Insert Text Into Website Textbox

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-chromedriver

For years I've used the code shown below to log into a website. It 1) opens Chrome, 2) allows me to manually step through the robot test page and 3) inserts my username. Today the macro is no longer able to insert my username.  It throws the following error:

> Run-time error '7':
>
> NoSuchElementError
>
> Element not found for Id=user

The relevant source code for the username input box is

```
  <input class="evo-input-text__input" type="email" name="user" id="user" style="text-transform:none">
```

so the element "id" is still "user".

**Why isn't the macro still able to insert my username and what code will insert my username?**

Here is the macro:

```
Sub Login_Selenium()
'
' Note: added reference to Selenium Type Library
'

Dim WDriver As New WebDriver
    
' Open Chrome and navigate to login page
    WDriver.Start "Chrome", ""
    WDriver.Get "https://www.prudential.com/login/"
 
' Maximize the window
    WDriver.Window.Maximize
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    
' On 03/04/23 the website now uses a "I'm not a robot" page. A msgbox is now used to allow the macro to proceed after you have manually completed the robot test.

       qq = MsgBox("Click through the ""I'm not a robot"" page and then click ""OK"" to proceed.")
        
' Enter the username -- this is the line that fails
    WDriver.FindElementById("user").SendKeys ("abcdefg")
'
' do other stuff
'
End sub
```

Comment: Has there been any changes outside of the macro? Such as the webdriver being updated? How long are you waiting from completing the robot check, to pressing okay on the message box?

Comment: @PhilGolding  Yes, chromedriver has been updated.  It takes about 3-5 seconds from the robot check complete to when OK button is clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the page source that is returned by the driver, you can see that the page code contains a lot of Java script code. I wrote the complete code that was returned by the driver into a file for further inspection:

```
WDriver.Get "https://www.prudential.com/login/"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
WriteTextfile WDriver.PageSource, Environ("Temp") & "\" & "SO78124249.txt"
```

using this piece of code

```
Sub WriteTextfile(txt, fileName As String)
    Dim file As Integer
    file = FreeFile
    If Dir(fileName) <> "" Then Kill fileName
    Open fileName For Output As #file
    Write #file, txt
    Close #file
End Sub
```

Now looking for the input form, I found this:

```
 <form class="login" method="POST" novalidate="" autocomplete="off"  
       id="evoLoginForm" data-qa="evoLoginForm" 
       action="https://www.prudential.com/api/public/platform/login/v1/ssologin">
 (...)
    <evo-input-text class="login__input input-username" 
                    input-name="user" input-type="email" a11y-aria-required="true" 
                    hide-asterisk=" type="box-label-outside" 
                    label="Username" error-messages=" styleurl="/etc.clientlibs/pru/clientlibs/clientlib-dependencies.min.css">
    </evo-input-text>
```

I am not a real HTML expert, but I assume that this `evo-input-text` is a custom tag and the Javascript code deals with it. What's interesting is that this element doesn't have an ID set. As your code uses this page source, it cannot find the ID.

I tried to locate the element by classname instead ("input-username"), and that worked:

```
Dim inputBox As WebElement
Set inputBox = WDriver.FindElementByClass("input-username")
inputBox.SendKeys "abcdefg"
```

**Update** Setting the password worked for me (only) by setting the focus first. I am not sure if there is any "Setfocus" method, but using `Click` did the trick:

```
Dim passwordBox As WebElement
Set passwordBox = WDriver.FindElementByClass("input-password")
passwordBox.Click
passwordBox.SendKeys "topsecret"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm going to test it a bit.  Why doesn't the same code using "input-password" insert the password?

Comment: Do you know why a construction like    WDriver.FindElementByCss("evo-input-text[class='input-username']").SendKeys ("abcdef")   doesn't work?

Comment: No, sorry, that's beyond my knowledge - especially when it comes to custom tags. But if I were you, I would split the command so that it's easier to find out what fails. Does `FindElementByCss` (or maybe better `FindElementsByCss`) find something? If yes: Does it find a specific element by class name? If yes: Is it possible to use `Sendkeys`? Currently, you do everything in one statement and you cannot tell what exactly fails (my bet, however would be that you can't search for custom tags).

Comment: "evo-input-text[class='input-username']"

Is a wrapper element around the input, which would explain why SendKeys wouldn't work. Clicking it does seem to select the input though, so you could try .Click first!

Comment: @PhilGolding  Nice, that works.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the website is making use of the Shadow DOM, and this may be causing issues with your Selenium selectors.

On the website, the following jQuery does select the correct element:

```
$("evo-input-text")[0].shadowRoot.getElementById('user')
```

I don't know Selenium too well, but after some searching, something similar to this should work:

```
WDriver.FindElementByTag("evo-input-text").GetShadowRoot().FindElementById("user").SendKeys("abcdefg")
```

**UPDATE**

After looking it up further online, I found a [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fx6uMiq7neo) video which uses Selenium in VBA. This video shows how to access the shadow DOM tree, as such:

```
Dim shadowRoot As WebElement
Set shadowRoot = WDriver.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", WDriver.FindElementByTag("evo-input-text"))
shadowRoot.FindElementById("user")
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't been able to get it to work, but I'll keep playing with it.

Comment: I just don't see any "GetShadowRoot" option in the drop-down box after I type "WDriver." in my code.

Comment: @ron, I've just updated the answer, after finding a helpful YouTube video that seems to show the shame issue as you've been having.